# Structure of f.g. modules over a non-commutative ring

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

To what extent is the structure theorem for finitely generated modules over principal ideal domains true over non-commutative domains? I'm in particular interested in non-commutative euclidean domains especially the twisted polynomial ring $K\langle X \rangle$ over a field $K$ (i.e. such that $Xa = \sigma(a)X$ for some automorphism $\sigma$ of K).

Comment: Your starting point seems a bit naive, even for the infinite dihedral group and its group ring.

Comment: I guess you interpret the group ring of $D_\infty$ as a twisted polynomial ring? Is the theory of f.g. modules over this group ring complicated?

Comment: @Charles, it would probably be more helpful to the OP if you explained your comment a little more.

Comment: OK, the representation theory of the infinite dihedral group over a field is a special case, in that the group ring is really twisted Laurent polynomials. You have to assume X acts invertibly, in other words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is thoroughly explored in Chapter 3 of Nathan Jacobson's *Theory of Rings*.  I took a quick look, and it looks like the analogous results go through in the noncommutative case.  For example, Theorem 19 in Chapter 3 states that a finitely-generated module over a noncommutative principal ideal domain is a direct sum of cyclic modules.